# Is "se" really a synonym of "verbo-pronominal"?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas

I notice that on the main site we have [se](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/se) as a synonym of [verbo-pronominal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbo-pronominal). Although I see that under many circumstance it is true that *se* is used as part of a pronominal verb that is not universally true. The tag excerpt for [se](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/se) in fact refers to reflexive verbs.

Comment: There are four main uses of se in Spanish. They can be looked up in the RAE. I was going to post all the definitions in Spanish but they need shortened forms and someone else who is a native Spanish speaker might want to tackle that.

Comment: You need at least three different tags for the Spanish usages.

Comment: @Lambie i was thinking f breaking the link between se and verbo-pronominal but not replacing it with extra tags. Would you like to make that an answer so people can comment on the way forward?

Comment: Yes, you could do away with the link but there are all the other uses. I prefer not to post anything as an answer because all my answers are trolled on this site. Sorry. :)

Answer (score 2):

The tag [se](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/se) may be unnecessary: it is difficult for new users to know about it, and since its mapping into [verbo-pronominal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbo-pronominal) it has been used just 6 times ([in almost 4 years](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)!).

In any case, this can be a good moment to make some ordering on the tags involving these kind of questions, which currently can use many of those without consistency:

- [reflexivos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reflexivos)
- [gramática](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gram%c3%a1tica)
- [pronombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronombres)
- [oraciones-impersonales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oraciones-impersonales)

I would suggest getting some sample questions, chose which ones should use and then adapt the rest accordingly. We did it in some other situations ([¿Qué etiquetas deberíamos utilizar para las preguntas del tipo "Diferencia entre la palabra X y Y"?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3048/1674) and [¿Cómo deberíamos etiquetar las preguntas sobre pronombres 'la', 'le' y 'lo' y en las que se observa laísmo, leísmo o loísmo?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2924/1674), for example) and worked well.

Related Meta questions:

- [Is there a difference really between [tag:reflexivos] and [tag:pronominales]](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2999/1674)

Answer (score 1):

I think the tags [se](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/se) and [verbo-pronominal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbo-pronominal) should not be synonyms. *Se* has many uses, and one of them are *[verbos pronominales](https://dle.rae.es/verbo#5TVOxkC)*. Other uses are [impersonal sentences](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31955/24236) or *[pasiva refleja](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32696/24236)*. *Se* itself is an [entry in the DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/se), so it would make sense as a tag.

Desynonymizing the tags would require some work of retagging the questions that do not refer to pronominal verbs, though. If there is enough support (and some volunteers to help with that work), we can do it.

Comment: Since I raised the issue I obviously have a moral obligation to help. Let me know when to start.

Comment: @mdewey I guess we can start when at least one (or better two) other users signal their agreement with an upvote on either the question or answer. I will let you know. I do not think it will be too much work: there are 72 questions, and I think most (as in "more than half") of them are rightly tagged [verbo-pronominal].

Comment: There has been just 6 renames since the tag was created https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: Please state more clearly which tags should not be synonyms. List the tags you want in Spanish. By the way, please do not say pronominal verbs in English. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you have to name the other tags.